# Finding all possible letter combinations from an inputted phone number

Tags: c#, algorithm, programming-challenge, recursion, combinatorics

[Prompt:](https://leetcode.com/problems/letter-combinations-of-a-phone-number/description/)

> Given a string containing digits from 2-9 inclusive, return all
>   possible letter combinations that the number could represent.
>
> A mapping of digit to letters (just like on the telephone buttons) is
>   given below. Note that 1 does not map to any letters.

I'm a relatively new LeetCoder and I feel pretty good about solving this problem. What are some obvious improvements that I could be making to improve the runtime or approach towards this problem or other problems in general?

```
public IList<string> LetterCombinations(string digits)
{
    string[] ph = new string[] { "0", "1", "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqrs", "tuv", "wxyz" };
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    if (digits == null || digits.Length == 0) return result;
    int len = ph[digits[0] - '0'].Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        GetCombos(digits, "", i, ref result, digits.Length);
    }

    return result;
}

public void GetCombos(string inputDigits, string curVariation, int charIndex, ref List<string> resultList, int length)
{
    string[] phone = new string[] { "0", "1", "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqrs", "tuv", "wxyz" };

    if (curVariation.Length != length)
    {
        char ch = phone[inputDigits[0] - '0'][charIndex];
        curVariation += ch;
    }
    if (curVariation.Length == length)
    {
        resultList.Add(curVariation);
        return;
    }

    string newInput = inputDigits.Substring(1, inputDigits.Length - 1);
    if (newInput == "") return;
    int numChars = phone[newInput[0] - '0'].Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < numChars; i++)
    {
        GetCombos(newInput, curVariation, i, ref resultList, length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is only one thing I really don't like:

You have the same array instantiated in two different places (the `phone/ph` array). Here it's fairly simple and easy to maintain, but IRL you should never do that.

You have two options to resolve this:

1) Create the `phone` array as a class field or property.

2) In the newest versions of C# you can place the recursive `GetCombos(...)` as an internal/local function inside `LetterCombinations(...)` and then only have `string[] phone = {...}` defined in the outer:

```
IList<string> LetterCombinations(...)
{
  string[] phone = { ... };

  void GetCombos(...)
  {
    ...
    char ch = phone[inputDigits[0] - '0'][charIndex];
    ...
  }  

  int len = phone[digits[0] - '0'].Length;
  ...
}
```

As shown the inner function can access the variables defines in the containing method.

---

Other things:

```
public void GetCombos(string inputDigits, string curVariation, int charIndex, ref List<string> resultList, int length) { ... }
```

You don't need the `ref` keyword because a list is a reference type.

---

I don't think `newInput` will ever be empty, so you can skip this check:

```
  if (newInput == "") return;
```

---

I would make this test

```
  if (digits == null || digits.Length == 0) return result;
```

as the first thing to do in the method:

```
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(digits)) return new List<string>();
```

(or maybe throw an exception?)

---

In `GetCombos(...)` you could use the `yield return` concept instead of the resultList argument as shown below:

```
public IList<string> LetterCombinations(string digits)
{
  if (digits == null || digits.Length == 0) return new List<string>();

  string[] phone = new string[] { "0", "1", "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqrs", "tuv", "wxyz" };

  List<string> result = new List<string>();

  IEnumerable<string> GetCombos(string inputDigits, string curVariation, int charIndex, int length)
  {
    if (curVariation.Length != length)
    {
      char ch = phone[inputDigits[0] - '0'][charIndex];
      curVariation += ch;
    }
    if (curVariation.Length == length)
    {
      yield return curVariation;
    }
    else
    {
      string newInput = inputDigits.Substring(1, inputDigits.Length - 1);
      int numChars = phone[newInput[0] - '0'].Length;

      for (int i = 0; i < numChars; i++)
      {
        foreach (string variation in GetCombos(newInput, curVariation, i, length))
        {
          yield return variation;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  int len = phone[digits[0] - '0'].Length;
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    result.AddRange(GetCombos(digits, "", i, digits.Length));
  }

  return result;
}
```

The LeetCode challenge states that the return value of `LetterCombinations(...)` should be `IList<string>`, but it would be more elegant to let it return `IEnumerable<string>` as well and then use `yield return` insted of `result.AddRange(GetCombos(...))` (you'll have to make it in a `foreach ()` loop though).

---

Just for the exercise I made my own version:

```
IEnumerable<string> LetterCombinations(string digits)
{
  string[] phone = new string[] { "0", "1", "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqrs", "tuv", "wxyz" };

  int length = digits.Length;

  IEnumerable<string> Runner(int buttonIndex, int digitIndex)
  {
    if (buttonIndex < 2 || buttonIndex > 9)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(digits));

    if (digitIndex == length)
    {
      foreach (char ch in phone[buttonIndex])
        yield return ch.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
      int newButtonIndex = digits[digitIndex] - '0';
      digitIndex++;

      foreach (char ch in phone[buttonIndex])
      {
        foreach (string tail in Runner(newButtonIndex, digitIndex))
        {
          yield return $"{ch}{tail}";
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return Runner(digits[0] - '0', 1);
}
```

Not to claim it to be better than yours - in fact it seems to be slightly slower - but just to show another approach.

In fact it can be done in one line using LINQ:

```
IEnumerable<string> LetterCombinations(string digits)
{
  string[] phone = new string[] { "0", "1", "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqrs", "tuv", "wxyz" };
  return digits.Skip(1).Select(d => d - '0').Aggregate(phone[digits[0] - '0'].Select(c => c.ToString()), (acc, i) => phone[i].SelectMany(c => acc.Select(a => $"{a}{c}")));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. The methods can be `static` since they do not access any class instance data.
2. The `ph` and `phone` arrays are used for the same purpose and are created on every call to the method. They should be a single `static readonly` field.
   2a. Remove some boilerplate by using array initializer syntax.
3. This feels like the perfect place for an iterator function (`yield return` syntax).
   3a. This means eliminating the `ref` parameter and converting the return types to `IEnumerable<string>`.
4. Use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` (or `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`) instead of checking explicitly for `null` or length zero.
5. Always wrap `if` blocks in curly braces, even if it is one statement. Future you will thank yourself if you have to maintain that code.
6. Give your code a bit of vertical breathing room. It's for programmers to read :)
7. Very minor nit, but it comes from me being old and living through the bad old days of early .NET frameworks: use `string.Empty` when you have a "" constant.

Here's what I wind up with as an initial cut:

```
private static readonly string[] phone = { "0", "1", "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqrs", "tuv", "wxyz" };

public static IEnumerable<string> LetterCombinations(string digits)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(digits))
    {
        yield break;
    }

    int len = phone[digits[0] - '0'].Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        foreach (string result in GetCombos(digits, string.Empty, i, digits.Length))
        {
            yield return result;
        }
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<string> GetCombos(string inputDigits, string curVariation, int charIndex, int length)
{
    if (curVariation.Length != length)
    {
        char ch = phone[inputDigits[0] - '0'][charIndex];

        curVariation += ch;
    }

    if (curVariation.Length == length)
    {
        yield return curVariation;
    }

    string newInput = inputDigits.Substring(1, inputDigits.Length - 1);

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newInput))
    {
        yield break;
    }

    int numChars = phone[newInput[0] - '0'].Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < numChars; i++)
    {
        foreach (string result in GetCombos(newInput, curVariation, i, length))
        {
            yield return result;
        }
    }
}
```